# Windows default media icon

Tags: windows, icons, media

Windows 7 upwards (I think) uses a built-in set of default icons for all media types; images, videos, music, etc. When looking the icons more closely with, for example, FileTypesMan the icon location is given as follows:

```
@{Microsoft.ZuneVideo_10.18052.10711.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.ZuneVideo/Files/Assets/FileExtension.png}
```

The icon can be used with that exact copy-paste with some success, but how could I extract the icon(s) from that source and use them properly as an .ico? I'm not looking the print screen all possible icon sizes and media usages to build a proper icon from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Icons in windows are usualy stored in DLL or EXE files.

See [Where to find most of Windows 10's native icons?](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/where-find-most-windows-10s-native-icons) for some examples.

You can use the freeware [Angus Johnson's Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to extract and save the icons to a proper .ico file.

Comment: As you can see in my post, the icon is not stored in a DLL or EXE as usual. Also, I was not able to open the location in the format with Resource Hacker.